# How to convert List<String> in Specific String Format?

Tags: apex, list, string

```
List<String> listoflang=new List<String>();
listoflang.add('Apex');
listoflang.add('PHP');
listoflang.add('Java');
```

and I want this list to be converted in string like this
Apex;PHP;Java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `String.join`, for example:

```
String.join(listOfLang, ';');
```

Check out the String documentation [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm) for more info.

Comment: you have beat me on this.